# Share text and website URL to Whatsapp from flutter

Tags: flutter, whatsapp

I am trying a send an invite of my app via button to certain contacts using the below logic.

```
static sendInvite(String number, String message) async {
    var whatsappAndroidUri =
        Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?phone=$number&text=$message");
    var whatsappIosUri =
        Uri.parse("https://wa.me/$number?text=${Uri.parse(message)}");

    try {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        await launchUrl(whatsappIosUri);
      } else {
        await launchUrl(whatsappAndroidUri);
      }
    } on Exception {
      Logger().d("$className: Can't launch WhatsApp");
    }
  }
```

It is working perfectly only for plain text. I am not able to send URL in message.